# Using QtCreator for rpi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt-creator

Can I use QtCreator and CMake to cross build for my rpi? I've already toolchain gcc 4.8.3 and I'm able to build program for my raspberry. Now I'm using scp and ssh to deploy my app but it's really frustrating this way.

I'm not interesed to use my RPI as build enviorment and I'm not interested to use Qt I want just build, debug and run from QtCreator... is it possible?

Any suggest?

Answer (score -1):

I needed to use Qt on Raspberry Pi a [couple of years ago](http://www.cmucam.org/boards/7/topics/2132?r=2141).

This is the guide I used: [Apt-get Qt4 on the Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.qt.io/Apt-get_Qt4_on_the_Raspberry_Pi):

```
sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
```

I've tested this on Raspberry Pi 2 recently and it works nicely (especially since there are more resources available)